# How to reduce screen tearing with X11 using ARM Mali GPU?

Tags: x11, performance, arm, mate-desktop, gpu

I am running [Parabola GNU/Linux](https://www.parabola.nu/) (based on Arch) on a Chromebook C201 (armv7). The device has an ARM Mali T764 GPU, which I am running with the free `panfrost` driver. Using Mate with X11, I am seeing quite a bit of screen tearing, for example when I move windows around.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326459/257802) to an older question worked like magic for me with an NVidia card I have on an x86 desktop. It pretty much eliminated all tearing. Is there any equivalent configuration option to that 'force full composition pipeline', either for X11 or Mali, that I could try to reduce screen tearing on my Chromebook?