# Graphics artifacts when using Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, graphics

I'm having this problem since I installed Ubuntu for a course that I'm doing.

I am getting graphics artifacts (see screenshot below) in many applications (some buttons on Zoom, but mostly on games like Minecraft, CSGO and Krunker.io).

If someone could help me I would be grateful.

[image: Bugs on krunker.io]

My hardware:

It's an old computer with a i3 processor(Intel® Core™ i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz × 4 ), a onboard graphic card(Intel® HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)) and 4GB of RAM

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS  |  Kernel 5.8.0-59-generic

Comment: Possibly related: [askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231824/)

Comment: Thanks Freddy, but i have already try this solutions, and unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182801/36176) ... if you can turn on something like "sync to vertical refresh" in your game, try that.

Comment: Thanks Murray, but not the solution yet. i'm gonna to see if there is any driver to update, and about the sync, he only thing related is the vsync, and i have tested whit that disabled and enabled. And I have edited the post with more info on the hardware :)

Comment: How about [this](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-intel-graphics-video-tearing.html) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234026/screen-tearing-on-ubuntu-xorg-20-04-with-intel-graphics)?

Comment: Didn't work too :(. The worst thing is that I didn't find any image similar to my screen in any place

Comment: How about [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349235)? (actually refers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348604))

Comment: PS: edit your question and show Ubuntu version and kernel version...

Comment: I'm gonna edit the post now, my kernel version is in the list :(. Is safe try to upgrade the kernel to 5.13?

Comment: Yes, try to upgrade to a newer kernel or downgrade, see [askubuntu.com/questions/1331116](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331116).

Comment: I checked a couple of our Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machines and the kernel version was 5.4.0 in both cases (actually 5.4.0-77-generic) ... how did you get you get 5.8.0-59-generic on your machine?

Comment: Firstly thanks you two by helping me, and i have just installed the ubuntu normaly, downloaded the iso, used Rufus to make a boot pendrive and installed this on mt machine

Comment: So, i have installed the version '5.13.0-051300-lowlatency' the triangles are gone finally.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1348604) ...

> ***OpenGL rendering missing some triangles, why and how to fix***
>
> *... it's an issue with Intel integrated graphics (often HD 2500) and kernels between 5.8.0-49 and 5.12.5.*

which may be fixed by

> *Installing a newer kernel or rolling back to an older one ...*

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310622/downgrade-to-kernel-5-4-0-because-kernel-5-8-45-doesnt-like-my-bluetooth-contro) may help with rolling back to an older kernel, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334229/how-to-update-my-just-my-kernel-version-on-ubuntu-20-04) may help with installing a newer kernel.